# Dot while extending Superclass in Java

Tags: java, android, class

What is the significance of dot(.) in the following piece of code.

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder>
```

Till now whatever programs I saw were something like

```
public class A extends B
```

But never encountered where dot is used.
And also , I know that <> is used for Generic classes ,but I unable to wrap my head around this :
 `class A extends B<A.C>` . What is the meaning of `<class.class>`  ? Thanks.

Comment: This just means the inner class `A.C` (where class `C` is defined inside class `A`) is the type parameter for class `B`. So in your case, a `GreenAdapter` is a special kind of `RecyclerView.Adapter` that only contains `GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder` objects.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView.Adapter is an inner class of RecyclerView.  Like this:

```
public class RecyclerView {
    public class Adapter {
```

You're extending the inner of the two classes, not the outer.